# Full Screen in customize theme

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

I need my app to show as full screen. Now I know how to add this feature into the application tag in Mainfest using

```
android:theme=”@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

However, I have my own theme called "CodeFont", and I cannot use two themes in the same application. How I can add this feature into my own style tag in my resources file? There is no such things as an android:style tag.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Create your custom theme by using default theme, like this

window with `Fullscreen`

```
<style name="generalnotitle" parent="general">
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

window with `NoTitle`

```
<style name="generalnotitle" parent="general">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: this does not do fullscreen. you need  <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>

Comment: In case someone wonders, put this on `res/values/styles.xml`.

Comment: When I do this with windowFullscreen set to false, it does the opposite of what I expect it to. It makes my dialog go completely fullscreen. Whereas without the custom theme, my dialog is just huge, taking up practically the entire screen (both width and height) uneccessarily. Why is that?

Answer (score 11):

Create your custom theme with parent attribute to inherit NoTitleBar.Fullscreen property from general android theme.

values/styles.xml

```
<resources> 
   <style name="CodeFont" parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
      <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item> 
      ...
   </style>
</resources>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity 
    android:name=".MainActivity" 
    android:theme="@style/CodeFont"> 
      ...
</activity>
```

Answer (score 6):

in style.xml add

```
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
```

to your theme. Example:

```
<style name="CodeFont" parent="android:Theme.Light">
     <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can request some features and flags in code by using ( for example ):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.some_layout);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting up a theme in app styles works for my React Native application. Just type in the `android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"></style>
</resources>
```

And in the `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` link to this theme:

```
<application
  ...
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

[Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html#Theme_Material_Light_NoActionBar_Fullscreen)