# Hide notification via theme

Tags: android, styles, themes

I know how to do this via java code, but I'm wondering how I can set this in my own custom theme. I've found

```
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

for hiding the application title bar, but is there an item that will hide the notification bar? I haven't been able to find this yet.

Answer (score 0):

From your question I assume you want fullscreen capability? Here's a [possible answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9859489/1325551/) that can at least give you an idea.